# windows bat file: how to strip the path-part from a absolute filepath

Tags: file, path, batch-file

i have a variable like this:

```
set file=c:\dir\foo\bar\file.txt
```

how can i get just the path-part into another variable?

```
echo %pathpart%
```

should give c:\dir\foo\bar\

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the equivalent of dirname() in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778135/how-do-i-get-the-equivalent-of-dirname-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Since some people coming here are wanting to get the filename part and not the directory, to save you time: use %~np to get only the filename and extension. For example, %~nx1 returns the value of %1 but without the drive letter or path (useful for drag-and-drop batch files). Without the extension is `~n`.

Comment: This answer provides a list of batch-script variable modifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3215539/1960180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I get the equivalent of dirname() in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778135/how-do-i-get-the-equivalent-of-dirname-in-a-batch-file)