# Batch: Remove file extension

Tags: file, batch-file

I have the following batch script from Wikipedia:

```
@echo off
    for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Ordner" %%f in (*.flv) do (
    echo %%f
)
pause
```

In the for-loop all files with the extension flv get echoed,
but I want the make some actions with the file(s)
where I need one time the file without the extension and one time with the extension.
How could I get these two?

I searched for solutions but I don't find one.
I'm a real newbie in batch...

Answer (score 387, accepted):

You can use `%%~nf` to get the filename only as described in the reference for [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for):

```
@echo off
    for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Ordner" %%f in (*.flv) do (
    echo %%~nf
)
pause
```

The following options are available:

```
Variable with modifier  Description

%~I                     Expands %I which removes any surrounding 
                        quotation marks ("").
%~fI                    Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.
%~dI                    Expands %I to a drive letter only.
%~pI                    Expands %I to a path only.
%~nI                    Expands %I to a file name only.
%~xI                    Expands %I to a file extension only.
%~sI                    Expands path to contain short names only.
%~aI                    Expands %I to the file attributes of file.
%~tI                    Expands %I to the date and time of file.
%~zI                    Expands %I to the size of file.
%~$PATH:I               Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment 
                        variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of 
                        the first one found. If the environment variable name is 
                        not defined or the file is not found by the search,
                        this modifier expands to the empty string.
```

Comment: Just a quick note: in the above example **%%f** would be something like `C:\Users\Admin\Ordner\foo.flv` and **%%~nf** would give you `foo`. If you want everything _except_ the extension use **%%~df%%~pf%%~nf** which would give you `C:\Users\Admin\Ordner\foo`

Comment: @ehambright Late comment, but I guess using `%%~dpnf` would be a shorter alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the modifier/ description table Dirk. My case was getting the file name without extension from param `%1` in a batch script. `echo %~n1` was what I was after.

Answer (score 40):

In case the file your variable holds doesn't actually exist the `FOR` approach won't work. One trick you could use, if you know the length of the extension, is taking a substring:

```
%var:~0,-4%
```

the `-4` means that the last 4 digits (presumably *.ext*) will be truncated.

Comment: This is not working for me (on Win8.1) -- maybe I misunderstand it when trying `echo %f:~0,-4%` in the context of the example used in the question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently that works for "normal" variables, not FOR variables (or maybe I just don't know the correct syntax). Anyway this will work in the context of the OP example: `SET fl=%%f` and then `echo %fl:~0,-4%`

Comment: @Wolf you need to set value of the loop variable to a normal variable then do string substitution/truncation in the normal variable

Comment: In more than enough cases, the extension length does not equal 3 or is unknown. You can still use a for even if the file does not exist, see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

**Without looping**

I am using this if I simply want to strip the extension from a filename or variable (without listing any directories or existing files):

```
for %%f in ("%filename%") do set filename=%%~nf
```

If you want to strip the extension from a full path, use `%%dpnf` instead:

```
for %%f in ("%path%") do set path=%%~dpnf
```

**Example:**

*(Use directly in the console)*

```
@for %f in ("file name.dat") do @echo %~nf
@for %f in ("C:\Dir\file.dat") do @echo %~dpnf

OUTPUT:

file name
C:\Dir\file
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm also a stranger to windows cmd, but try this:

```
echo %%~nf
```

Answer (score 11):

If your variable is an argument, you can simply use `%~dpn` (for paths) or `%~n` (for names only) followed by the argument number, so you don't have to worry for varying extension lengths.

For instance `%~dpn0` will return the path of the batch file without its extension, `%~dpn1` will be `%1` without extension, etc.

Whereas `%~n0` will return the name of the batch file without its extension, `%~n1` will be `%1` without path and extension, etc.

The full thing is `%~dpfn0` and it starts to make sense, when you take a closer look:

- **d** is **d**rive
- **p** is **p**ath
- **n** is **n**ame
- **x** is e**x**tension, and
- **fn** is **f**ile**n**ame with extension

Comment: Thank you! `%~dpn` kept the whole file path except the extension as wanted, while `%~nf` kept the extension somehow.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. yes, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer to give a little bit more insight into the letters.

Comment: **f** is **f**ilename, **x** is e**x**tension

Comment: +1 for the meaning of these letters. I dislike batch (but use anyway), so I usually copy/paste these without giving much thought to these letters. Now, I know :)

Answer (score 9):

This is a really late response, but I came up with this to solve a particular problem I had with DiskInternals LinuxReader appending '.efs_ntfs' to files that it saved to non-NTFS (FAT32) directories :

```
@echo off
REM %1 is the directory to recurse through and %2 is the file extension to remove
for /R "%1" %%f in (*.%2) do (
    REM Path (sans drive) is given by %%~pf ; drive is given by %%~df
    REM file name (sans ext) is given by %%~nf ; to 'rename' files, move them
    copy "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.%2" "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf"
    echo "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.%2" copied to "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf"
echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: I'm not sure it answers the asked question, but it actually helped me, thanks!

Comment: @matan7890 True; the op doesn't specify what "I want the make some actions with the file(s)" [sic] entails, but one of those actions may be renaming them, in which case my answer is an expansion of the accepted answer.

Comment: This helped a friend of mine who opened an attachment and had `.encrypted` added to all his files, along with a ransom demand.  Apparently the attacking script must have been a batch file that is the reverse of this and added `.encrypted` to all files.

Comment: upvoted because you mention the drive, path, and extension (**%%~df%%~pf%%~nf**) which most closely resembles the output of **%%f** from the orginal question, instead of *just* the filename without extension (**%%~nf**)

Answer (score 1):

Using cygwin bash to do the chopping

```
  :: e.g. FILE=basename.mp4 => FILE_NO_EXT=basename
  set FILE=%1
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('bash -c "FILE=%FILE%; echo ${FILE/.*/}" ') do set FILE_NO_EXT=%%a
```