# Batch: Remove a string from a string

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I have the following batch script from Wikipedia:

```
@echo off
    for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Ordner" %%f in (*.flv) do (
    echo %%f
)
pause
```

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension) that `%%~nf` returns just the filename without the extension.
Now I just wanted to remove `(Video)` from the filenames (`%%~nf`).
How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\Leniel\Desktop\BatchTest" %%f in (*.flv) do (
    call :Sub %%~nf 
    )

:Sub
set str=%*
set str=%str:(Video)=%
echo %str%
pause
```

Take a look at the following link to learn about removing a substring using string substitution:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Remove

Comment: I took already a look but %%f seems not the be the same as for e.g. %str%