# batch script replace variable string within string

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I remove 
// remove absolute path string from fullPath string

```
set abs_p=C:\abspath\
set rel_p=C:\abspath\foo\boo\bar
```

How can I remove the abs_p from the rel_p?
I'm not getting the syntax working

```
set rel_p=%rel_p:abs_p=%
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216475/batch-remove-a-string-from-a-string

Comment: thanks but my problem is the string to replace is a variable and I'm not seeing how to specify a variable inside this command, it escapes the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your sample input this script produces

> foo\boo\bar

```
set abs_p=C:\abspath\
set rel_p=C:\abspath\foo\boo\bar

set newp=
set rec_a=
set rec_r=

call :strip  %rel_p%\ %abs_p%
goto :END

:strip
set rec_a_part=
set rec_a=
set rec_r_part=
set rec_r=

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%t  in ("%2") do (
    set rec_a_part=%%t
    set rec_a=%%u
 )
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%t  in ("%1") do ( 
  set rec_r_part=%%t
  set rec_r=%%u
)
if not !%newp%!==!! set newp=%newp%\
if not !%rec_a_part%!==!%rec_r_part%! set newp=%newp%%rec_r_part%
if not !%rec_r%!==!! call :strip  %rec_r% %rec_a%
goto :EOF

:END
echo %newp%
```

Comment: exactly what I needed but dam! any way to make it simpler?

Comment: Simpler? Yes, use vbscript, or wscipt or powershell, in other words: a decent programming language. If it fits your need don't forget to mark my answer as correct as well for the answers for on other questions you have asked.

Answer (score 5):

A quick and dirty solution that works as long as abs_p does not contain `=` or `!`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "abs_p=C:\abspath\"
set "rel_p=C:\abspath\foo\boo\bar"

set "rel_p=!rel_p:*%abs_p%=!"
echo relative path = !rel_p!
```

A quick solution that should work always.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "abs_p=C:\abspath\"
set "rel_p=C:\abspath\foo\boo\bar"

>temp.txt echo !abs_p!
for %%N in (temp.txt) do set /a len=%%~zN-2
set "rel_p=!rel_p:~%len%!"
del temp.txt

echo relative path = !rel_p!
```

The above uses a crude but effective method to get the string length of the absolute path. There is a more complex but screaming fast [strLen function](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.strLen) that can be used instead.