# How do I remove extension for renaming purposes?

Tags: file, batch-file, batch-rename

I have code that looks like this

> %original%-added.txt

So if the original filename is

> blue.txt

My code modifies that blue.txt file and the new file is then named

> blue.txt-added.txt

How can I remove that first ".txt" so that I only get

> blue-added.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch: Remove file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension)

Comment: You should show your code that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
%original:~0,-4%-added.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a simple REN command is all you need. I'm assuming you always want to preserve the original file extension.

```
ren "%original%" "?????????????????????-added.*"
```

Just make sure there are at least as many `?` as there are characters in the original name up until the `.`

Here are some results you can expect

```
original          new
--------          ------------
blue.txt          blue-added.txt
part1.part2.txt   part1-added.part2.txt
```

You could use wildcards in your source file mask. The following would append "-added" to the base name of all .txt files:

```
ren *.txt ?????????????????????-added.*
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) if you want to understand why this works.