# Remove unneccessary file extensions from name

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm trying to convert a bunch of OGG files to M4A using a program called Super. Only problem is that this program adds the extension you're trying to convert to after the source extension.

So, if I convert a file named `Keyboard.ogg` to an M4A file, it converts it to an M4A, but the resulting file name is `Keyboard.ogg.M4A`.

What I want to do is when the conversion finishes, I want to run a command or batch script on every file ending in `.ogg.M4A` so that the result is `Keyboard.m4a` instead of `Keyboard.ogg.M4A` (The file extension should be lower case since a program I am using to develop a video game requires both `.ogg` and `.m4a` files for exports (since it uses OGG for PC exports and M4A for Mobile exports) and I think it might be case sensitive.)

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension), but when using `%%~nf` it only removes the .M4A part (instead of the `.ogg.M4A`) and if I were to rename that I'd be back at square 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of your file names contain any additional dots other than `.ogg.M4A`, then all you need is a single `REN` command.

```
ren *.ogg.M4A ??????????????????????????????.m4a
```

Be sure to use enough `?` to match the longest name in your file set.

See [How does the Windows RENAME (REN) command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for a full explanation of how REN handles wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.ogg.M4A" '
 ) DO (
 FOR %%b IN ("%%~na") DO (
  ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%~nb.m4a"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Take the name of each file in the source directory that fits the mask "*.ogg.m4a"

Using the name part of the filenamename, rename using the name part only +the required extension.