# Conversion of dpn, type commands from windows to bash

Tags: linux, bash

I recently try linux (from windows), and I find it difficult to process my following windows command to linux bash.

The windows command was:

```
set /p cutoff=Set BLAST E-Value Cutoff[1e-]:
for %%F in (*.fa) do program.exe -parameter1 %%F -parameter2_cutoff 1e-%cutoff% -output_file %%~dpnF.fas & type %%F %%~dpnF.fas > %%~dpnF.txt
```

This script takes a numeric value from user and uses it to run a program in every .fa files on a folder with the desired cutoff. Here %%~dpnF takes only the filename (without file extension). In this very script, I join the content of each input file (.fa) and its generated output (.fas) and finally merge them in final output (.txt). Here, for each Input file, there will be a final output file.

To run it in ubuntu , I try

```
echo "Set BLAST E-Value Cutoff[1e-]:"
read cutoff
for $f in *.fa; do program -parameter1 $f -parameter2_cutoff 1e-$cutoff -output_file $~dpnF.fas & cat $f $~dpnF.fas > $~dpnF.txt; done
```

Immediately it shows that linux is not supporting dpn type of command in windows and also the scripts terminates abruptly, showing no output.

Although I understand the different file extensions are not very meaningful in linux, but I have to keep it this way for other programs to process them.

I appreciate any type of help.

Thanks

Comment: Your requirements are not clear! Give a minimal verifiable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence %~dpn is used to get:

1. %~d - The drive
2. %~p - The path
3. %~n - The file name

Check [the meaning of all expansions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215539/6843677).

The drive has no meaning in Linux. The path, full or partial, could be extracted with the command `dirname` and the filename could be extracted with the command `basename`.

The sequence `%%~dpn` means to get the whole pathname from root (`/`).

In fact, you do not need that in Linux, if a list of files was created with `*.f`, the list of files will be relative to the "present working directory" (command `pwd`), no need to extend them.

And to strip the extension from a filename, use `${f%.*}`.
That cuts the string in "$f" at the last dot `.` and anything that follows `*`.
Then just add the extension you want: `${f%.*}.fas`

Also, the character & has the meaning of "run the previous command in the background", which is not what you want.

And finally, the `for $f` should be replaced by `for f`.

This is a cleaner translation:

```
echo "Set BLAST E-Value Cutoff[1e-]:"
read cutoff
for f in *.fa; do 
    program -parameter1 "$f" \
            -parameter2_cutoff "1e-$cutoff" \
            -output_file "${f%.*}.fas"
    cat "$f" "${f%.*}.fas" > "${f%.*}.txt"
 done
```

Comment: That's a nice interpretation of the OP's requirement! `+1`