# Windows batch script for renaming files to remove their extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a lot of files in a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) directory named `*.mkv.bin` e.g.:

```
American Pie 1.mkv.bin
```

I want to rename these files using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to delete `.bin` as follows:

```
American Pie 1.mkv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: Remove file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /R "I:\" %%f IN (*.mkv.bin) DO REN "%%f" "%%~nf"
```

working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Stack Overflow Answer

set /p f=File to rename(drive and path):
set /p e=Extension to rename to:
set /p nf=File name to rename to:
echo Renameing...
@ren "%f%" "%e%.%nf%"
cls && echo Done! && pause >nul
exit
```

> > > > add this text a rename.bat file and run it!