# Get a filename with a specific extension from a directory

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to Get a filename with a specific extension from a directory. Then in a result, I want to get rid of the extension name.

```
enter code here
@echo off
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
   if "%%~xf"==".pdf" echo %%f
)
```

Let say in the directory the pdf files are (one.pdf, two.pdf, and three.pdf)

In the command above the results are

- one.pdf
- two.pdf
- three.pdf

my preferred results are:

- one
- two
- three

Thanks in Advance
Ryl

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension Regards,
Ryl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cut command to remove the '.pdf'.
For example, this will print out 'one':

```
echo 'one.pdf' | cut -d'.' -f 1
```

Comment: NB: This uses '.' as a delimiter and returns the part before the first '.'. So if you have multiple periods in your filename you'll need a different solution

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your prompt reply. I found code that I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension - Thanks Again