# Programatically get system32 path in command prompt

Tags: path, environment-variables, command-prompt, system32

I'm using a command process in another program that for some odd reason does not have the `system32` set in the path environment variable. I can use the `%comspec%` variable to get the path `C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe`, but I need to just have the folder by itself.

I am not overly familiar with command prompt programming; is there a way that I can just add the `system32` (or equivalent) path programmatically?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778135/how-do-i-get-the-equivalent-of-dirname-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Personally, I'd try googling "Path Editor". Your quest is not clear. DO you just want to add the system32 directory to the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it appears that there is no environment variable for obtaining the system32 folder (or its equivalent) on a system, I did find a solution involving string manipulation. The following block of code will add the folder where the cmd.exe path is located:

```
SET str=%ComSpec%
SET str=%str:cmd.exe=%
SET PATH=%PATH%;%str%
```

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean programmatically? If you're refering to a variable, there is no standard variable for system32. However you could use `%WINDIR%\system32` or `%systemroot%\system32`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I needed to get the system32 folder or its equivalent on different windows systems

Comment: Has this answer helped you?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not, sorry.

Comment: `%systemroot%\system32` might be better, see [What is difference between %WinDir% and %SystemRoot%?](https://superuser.com/a/638335/903729)

Answer (score -2):

It is very nice answer. i have tried and worked out. This problem comes with window7 OS probably.

```
    SET str=%ComSpec%
    SET str=%str:cmd.exe=%
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%str%
```

Comment: Please put comments into the comments, not as an answer of it's own.