# same package.json doesn't run in windows and mac

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting the following error when I am try to start my app in windows.

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
[0]           ^^^^
[0] ^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Any explanations or packages that I am missing?

Here is my package.json, please let me know some of the scripts that are mac specific and might lead to the above error, from my analysis it is around server or update:watch
package.json

```
{
  "name": "documentation-playground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run update:watch\"",
    "server": "node --max_old_space_size=8192  ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve --aot --progress false --proxy-config proxy.config.json --port 8888",
    "mock": "node json-server/json-server.js",
    "update:watch": "onchange \"json-server/**/*.json\" -i -- npm run mock",
    "npm-install": "rimraf ./src/app/core && rimraf ./node_modules/woa-core-ng-module && npm i",
    "test": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run mock\" \"ng test --source-map=false\"",
    "start-prod": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server-prod\" \"npm run update:watch\"",
    "server-prod": "ng serve --configuration=production --progress true --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "start-demo": "ng serve --configuration=demo",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ./dist/public",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:clean",
    "build:aot": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --aot",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --configuration=production --deploy-url=documentation-playground/",
    "prebuild:demo": "npm run build:clean",
    "build:demo": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --configuration=demo --deploy-url=documentation-playground/",
    "postbuild:demo": "mv ./dist/public/documentation-playground/documentation-playground-index.html ./dist/public/documentation-playground/index.html",
    "postbuild": "rimraf ./dist/public/documentation-playground/assets/i18n/en.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "jsonschema": "1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-responsive": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0",
    "stacktrace-js": "2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "cp-cli": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "onchange": "^3.2.1",
    "concurrently": "3.4.0",
    "json-server": "0.9.6",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778135/how-do-i-get-the-equivalent-of-dirname-in-a-batch-file

Comment: This is incomplete. Do provide what does your `package.json` looks like what are you trying to acheive with what command.

Comment: Also, how are you running it on windows? If you're not using bash (for example, if you're using cmd.com) then Windows don't have the same command line as Mac/Linux. For example `ls` on Mac is `dir` on Windows

Comment: Sorry added the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes minor version changes can break things. There might be some monor version change happened from the time you did `npm install` on your Mac and by the time you did on Window. So, it is advised to keep the `package-lock.json` in git and update it whenever you are updating your `package.json`. Also, not that not all packages are compatible with all the platforms. I am sure you can identify the problem causing node module by the call stack.