# PowerShell eqivalent of POSIX dirname

Tags: powershell, dirname

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778135/how-do-i-get-the-equivalent-of-dirname-in-a-batch-file) asks about how to get the directory name of a path in a batch script.

How does one do the equivalent of [POSIX `dirname`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) in PowerShell?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `Split-Path $pathString`